# Script with utf-8 text runs differently from RStudio and command line in Windows

Tags: r, regex, windows, utf-8

I'm working with files containing text in Hindi and parsing them. I wrote my code in Rstudio and executed it without many issues. But now, I need to execute the same script from command line using R.exe/Rscript.exe and it doesn't work the same way. I've run a simple script from both RStudio and the terminal:

```
n_p<-'नाम'

Encoding(n_p)

gregexpr(n_p,c('adfdafc','नाम adsfdfa'))
sessionInfo()
```

Output In RStudio:

```
> n_p<-'नाम'
> 
> Encoding(n_p)
[1] "UTF-8"
> 
> gregexpr(n_p,c('adfdafc','नाम adsfdfa'))
[[1]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1

[[2]]
[1] 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 3

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=English_India.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rJava_0.9-10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0
```

Output with R.exe in cmd (For debugging purposes. Rscript.exe gives a similar if not identical output)

```
> n_p<-'à☼"à☼_à☼r'
>
> Encoding(n_p)
[1] "latin1"
>
> gregexpr(n_p,c('adfdafc','à☼"à☼_à☼r adsfdfa'))
[[1]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1

[[2]]
[1] 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 9

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_India.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0
```

I've tried changing locales but `Sys.setlocale` refuses to work properly. In some cases, `gregexpr` gives an error when it can't parse non ASCII code. And finally, when it does run without errors, it doesn't match regular expressions properly. I can't provide a reproducible example at the moment, but I will try to later.

Help.

Comment: What is your expectation here? what is your objective, I understand two different output you are receiving but I am sorry but I could not able to understand what problem you are trying to solve( the overview,  like why you are using regexpr ?, what is the string you are trying to match?...etc. etc ) . Thanks

Comment: Try `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` at the start of your script

Comment: Try to execute the script like this: `eval(parse(filename, encoding="UTF-8"))`

Comment: use in your Rscript `str_conv` from the `stringr` package [(info here)](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_conv.html) to convert your string. At least working for me when I pass a string to Rscript via an argument.

Answer (score 6):

The right answer is that you should run Rscript with the option --encoding=file encoding

There is no need to set locale, and as you probably found out, it doesn't work anyway. If your file is UTF-8:
Rscript.exe --encoding=UTF-8 file.R

Comment: In Windows it worked for me characters like `à` or `é` but it fails with `<ERROR: re-encoding failure from encoding 'UTF-8'>` for character like `λ`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that R is running in a suitable locale:

Running rterm use: `Sys.getlocale()` to find your current locale.

You can set your locale using:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "hi-IN")

# Try "hi-IN.UTF-8" too...
```

You can find locale names [here](https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php), the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/language-strings), and [here](https://ss64.com/locale.html).

If you have the correct value, put the `Sys.setlocale()` command in your `~/.Rprofile`.

**References**

- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html
- http://withr.me/configure-character-encoding-for-r-under-linux-and-windows/