# Encoding discrepancy in RScript

Tags: r

I have been struggling with an encoding problem with a program that needs to run both in RStudio and using RScript.  After wasting half a day on this I have a kludgy workaround, but would like to understand why the RScript version marks a string as latin1 when it is in fact UTF-8, and whether there is a better alternative to my solution.  Example:

```
x <- "Ø28"
print(x)
print(paste("Marked as", Encoding(x)))
print(paste("Valid UTF = ", validUTF8(x)))
x <- iconv(x, "UTF-8", "latin1")
print(x)
```

In RStudio, the output is:

```
[1] "Ø28"
[1] "Marked as latin1"
[1] "Valid UTF =  FALSE"
[1] NA
```

and when run using RScript from a batch file in Windows the output from the same code is:

```
[1] "Ã\23028"
[1] "Marked as latin1"
[1] "Valid UTF =  TRUE"
[1] "Ø28"
```

In the latter case, it does not strike me as entirely helpful that a string defined within an R program by a simple assignment is marked as Latin-1 when in fact it is UTF-8.  The solution I used in the end was to write a function that tests the actual (rather than declared) encoding of character variables using validUTF8, and if that returns TRUE, then use iconv to convert to latin1.  It is still a bit of a pain since I have to call that repeatedly, and it would be better to have a global solution.  There is quite a bit out there on encoding problems with R, but nothing that I can find that solves this when running programs with RScript.  Any suggestions?

R 3.5.0, RStudio 1.1.453, Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 (don't ask...)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761765/script-with-utf-8-text-runs-differently-from-rstudio-and-command-line-in-windows

Comment: Related, but unfortunately not helpful.  Adding options(encoding = "latin1") at the start of the script does not change the output with either scenario (RScript gives UTF-8 encoding marked as Latin-1), and the locale is correctly set.